# image upload problem

Tags: php, image, upload

I wrote a function to resize and upload images...it works, but only for one image. So if I call the function three times, I end up with 3 copies of the last image.....

```
function uploadImage($name,$width,$height,$size,$path='content/user_avatars/')
{
    //===================================================
    //Handle image upload
    $upload_error=0;
    //Picture
    $img = $_FILES[$name]['name'];
    if($img)
    {
        $file = stripslashes($_FILES[$name]['name']);
        $ext = strtolower(getExt($file));

        if($ext!='jpg' && $ext!='jpeg' && $ext!='png' && $ext!='gif')
        {
            $error_msg = "Unknown extension";
            $upload_error = 1;
            return array($upload_error,$error_msg);
        }

        if(filesize($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])>$size*1024)
        {
            $error_msg = "Max file size of ".($size*1024)."kb exceeded";
            $upload_error = 2;
            return array($upload_error,$error_msg);
        }

        $newFile = time().'.'.$ext;

        resizeImg($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'],$ext,$width,$height);
        $store = copy($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'],$path.$newFile);
        if(!$store)
        {
            $error_msg = "Uploading failed";
            $upload_error = 3;
            return array($upload_error,$error_msg);
        }
        else
        {
            return array($upload_error,$newFile);
        }
    }
}

//=========================================================================================

//Helper Functions
function getExt($str)
{
    $i = strpos($str,".");
    if(!$i)
    {
        return "";
    }
    $l = strlen($str)-$i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
}

function resizeImg($file,$ext,$width,$height)
{
    list($aw,$ah) = getimagesize($file);
    $scaleX = $aw/$width;
    $scaleY = $ah/$height;

    if($scaleX>$scaleY)
    {
        $nw = round($aw*(1/$scaleX));
        $nh = round($ah*(1/$scaleX));
    }
    else
    {
        $nw = round($aw*(1/$scaleY));
        $nh = round($ah*(1/$scaleY));
    }


    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($nw,$nh);
    imagefill($new_image,0,0,imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image,255,255,255,127));
    if($ext=='jpg'||$ext=='jpeg')
    {
        $src_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    }
    else if($ext=='gif')
    {
        $src_image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
    }
    else if($ext=='png')
    {
        $src_image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    }
    imagecopyresampled($new_image,$src_image,0,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$aw,$ah);

    if($ext=='jpg'||$ext=='jpeg')
    {
        imagejpeg($new_image,$file,100);
    }
    else if($ext=='gif')
    {
        imagegif($new_image,$file);
    }
    else if($ext=='png')
    {
        imagepng($new_image,$file,9);
    }

    imagedestroy($src_image);
    imagedestroy($new_image);
}
```

I have a form with two upload fields, 'face_pic' and 'body_pic', and I want to upload these two to the server and resize them before storing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
md5(microtime())
```

Try naming it like this.

Or try something like this...

```
function slikeAvatar($slika,$id = 0){
    copy($slika, "avatari/{$id}l.jpg");
    $gfx = new Thumbnail($slika, 200);
    $gfx->save("avatari/{$id}.jpg");
    unset($gfx);
    $gfx = new Thumbnail($slika, 75);
    $gfx->save("avatari/{$id}s.jpg");
    unset($gfx);
    slikeCrop("avatari/{$id}s.jpg","avatari/{$id}s.jpg"); 
}
```

slike = images

Answer (score 1):

You use the current time to determine the resulting name of the file. The function executes so fast, that `time()` yields the same result for both images.

Use some other means to disambiguate the resulting name of the file. Best choice would be to pass the resulting name as a parameter. That way, the environment can determine how the file is named. Candidates are primary key of the meta information (in case they are stored in the database), original file name, universally unique identifier.

In any case, check whether the resulting name is a legal filename on your platform and that you do not accidentally overwrite files.

Also consider using [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move the file from the temporary location to the destination. That function does some security checking.

Comment: so how do I solve the situation? And I don't think that is the problem, since the file is being saved with different names, meaning it picks different timestamps.